# Android custom listview layout to another layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have a custom `ListView` layout that I got from a website.  It allows me to click on an item from a list and repopulates the same layout with a new list of different items based on the item you clicked. The layout works fine and I got it to populate with information pulled from a database.

The problem that Im having is that instead of having it repopulate the layout with a new list when clicked, I would like it to go to another layout.  I tried a couple things but had no luck. Here is my code.  Thank you for the help in advance:

```
public class firstactivity extends ListActivity {
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private Vector<RowData> data;
RowData rd;
CustomAdapter adapter;
int pos=1;
public int picpos = 0;
LinkedList<String> region = new LinkedList<String>();

String name = null;
String something = null;
    private Integer[] imgid = {          
        R.drawable.icon
        };

RelativeLayout layr1;
Animation ar3;  



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    data = new Vector<RowData>();

    String finaline = "";
       //Get info from database            
       InputStream is = null;

       String result = "";
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        //http connection
        try{
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2:8888/PhpProject1/index.php");
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                is = entity.getContent();

        }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
        }

        //convert response to string
        try{
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();
                result=sb.toString();
        }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
        }
        //parse json data
        try{
                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                        JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        Log.i("log_tag"," names: "+json_data.getString("name")

                        );
                        //Get an output to the screen
                        finaline = "\n\t" + jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        something = finaline.substring(finaline.indexOf(',',10));
                        name = something.substring(9,finaline.indexOf('\"', 9));

                        region.add(something);


                }
        }catch(JSONException e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
        }

    //set list with information from database
    for(int i=0;i<region.size();i++){

        try {
            rd = new RowData(i,region.get(i));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
         data.add(rd);
    }
    adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, R.layout.second_list,R.id.title, data);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    //getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);

  }
/*private OnClickListener SaveListener = new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v){
        setContentView(R.layout.newlayout);
    }
};*/

/*protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
{
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    setContentView(R.layout.newlayout);
    //final Intent intent = new Intent();
    //startActivityForResult(intent, position);
}*/

public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id) { 
    adapter = (CustomAdapter) parent.getAdapter();
    data.removeAllElements();
    //String insert_list;
    ////
    //if(position==0) {
        /*setContentView(R.layout.newlayout);
        TextView textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        textView1.setText((String)region.get(0));*/

    //setListAdapter(adapter);
    //getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    if(position == 0)
        setContentView(R.layout.newlayout);
}

private class RowData {

    protected int mId;
    protected String mTitle;

    RowData(int id,String title){
    mId=id;
    mTitle = title;
}
    @Override
    public String toString() {
            return mId+" "+mTitle;
    }
```

}

```
private class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RowData> {

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource,
                    int textViewResourceId, List<RowData> objects) {
            super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder = null;

            TextView title = null;
            TextView detail = null;
            ImageView i11=null;

            RowData rowData= getItem(position);

            if(null == convertView){
                    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.second_list, null);
                    holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
                    convertView.setTag(holder);                   
            }
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();    

            title = holder.gettitle();     
            title.setText(rowData.mTitle);



            i11=holder.getImage();
            i11.setImageResource(imgid[0]);

            return convertView;
    }




    private class ViewHolder {      
        private View mRow;
        private TextView title = null;
        private TextView detail = null;
        private ImageView i11=null;            

            public ViewHolder(View row) {
            mRow = row;
            }

            public TextView gettitle() {
                    if(null == title){
                            title = (TextView) mRow.findViewById(R.id.title);
                    }
                    return title;
            }


            public ImageView getImage() {
                if(null == i11){

                    i11 = (ImageView) mRow.findViewById(R.id.img); 
            }

            return i11;
    }

}
}
```

}

Comment: Its really hard to understand what your app is supposed to do, and what the problem is.  You might want to try writing a more concise explanation/question.

Comment: let me try this again, this code pulls strings from a database and creates a list, using a custom listview list on an xml layout called second_list. each item on the list is clickable. the original code that i got from a website made it so when you click on an item it cleared the data on the second_list and added a new list for example: when opening the application we had a list:

Comment: "Illinois","Indiana","Iowa","Kansas","Kentucky","Louisiana","Maine". when clicking on illinois it would create a new list with areas within illinois which in this case were: "Chicago metropolitan area", "Champaign-Urbana Metropolitan Area","Central Illinois","Southern Illinois","Shawnee Hills","Fox Valley","Metro-East","American Bottom".

Comment: what i would like to do is instead of recreating the list with a new list on the same layout i would like it to go to another layout for example in this case if i click on illinois it will send me to another screen that has a picture of illinois and a little background information. i figure a setContentView(R.layout.newlayout); would be enough to send it to another screen but it doesnt work, hopefully this helped understand the problem that i have thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like what you are looking for is a way to go to a new `Activity` and display a new `ListView`.  To go to a new Activity you would do something like:

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class));
```

This line of code is creating a new `Intent` object, which tells Android which `Activity` to open next.  You are then passing that `Intent` to the `startActivity` method of your current `Activity`.  A more detailed explanation is here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities

It also might be useful for you to pass some information to the next `Activity`, like the name of a state which was selected.  You can do that by putting this information into the Intent object:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("state", "New York");
startActivity(intent);
```

You can get this data from within `SecondActivity` by doing:

```
Intent incomingIntent = getIntent();
String state = incomingIntent.getExtras().getString("state");
```

`SecondActivity` refers to a new class which extends `Activity` that you will need to define in your code.  ***Don't forget to add it to your manifest.xml too***, otherwise you will get an exception when trying to start it.

Comment: thank you for the help, I am still new to android and this is helping me alot! I tried to do what you told me, but I am still getting an error, I am not adding the activity in the manifest.xml the right way this is how I have it now: <activity android:name=".firstactivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"><intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
             <activity android:name=".SecondActivity">
             </activity>

Comment: Its hard for me to tell by looking at what you pasted.  If you are getting a second error, it would be best to post a new question on SO.